# Jquery drag and drop - click event registers on drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jquery drag and drop.  The draggable element is a div with two nested divs floated left and right. On drop, the left nested div (which contains the text), gets enabled for a click event:

```
$('.element_left').click(function(e) {  
        window.open(ui.draggable.attr('data-link'));
});
```

Now on drop, sporadically, the click event fires off opening the link in the data-link for the draggable.  It looks like it fires off when the draggable number doesn't match the slot number, but not 100% on this.

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/f2bbt/

Weird...  You may need to try a few times to get this happening, drag the element to the edge of the slot so that the slot highlights.  The draggable immediately below the 'Extract RNA' seems to do this more than others...and when it happens the wrong page is loaded...should be element_8.html, but instead it opens a new page for element_1.html (which belongs to Isolate Virus element).

Comment: To recreate the issue drag and drop `isolate virus` to first slot and if you click on any draggable item a new window will get opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is to add the click handler to the element which was dropped, instead of that you were adding the click handler to all elements with class `element_left`

You need to change it to

```
ui.draggable.click(function(e) {  
    window.open(ui.draggable.attr('data-link'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K3XcF/)

Comment: Yes...that was the problem OK, and that is what the code originally was.  I changed it so that the user had to click on the div holding the text as I added a button in the nested right hand div which displays a tooltip (code not in fiddle..).  I know you have answered the question, but any ideas how I could do this.  Should I open another question?

Comment: @PeterBrowne probably you could ask another question with an appropriate fiddle demo

Comment: @PeterBrowne Can you explain the problem again

Comment: The little square in the top right corner of the draggables containing the letter i is a button.  Clicking this brings up a tooltip.  So I needed to seperate the draggable into left right divs so that only the text in the left div opens the data-link.  The right div containing the info button is seperate.  I guess I could try something like ui.draggable.parent().find('.element_left').click(function(e) {

Comment: @PeterBrowne can you post it as a different question otherwise my answer and the new situation will not be matching. If you can post a link to the new question I can have a look

Comment: OK...I will post a new question and fiddle

Comment: @PeterBrowne try `ui.draggable.find('.info').click(function(e) {  
    window.open(ui.draggable.attr('data-link'));
});`, if you have posted another question share the link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432605/jquery-drag-and-drop-set-clickable-region-in-draggable-on-drop

Comment: @PeterBrowne checkout the above comment and check whether it is working

Comment: Not sure what the point is with that code...info is always clickable (and element_left is clickable on drop...) with ui.draggable.parent().find('.element_left').click(function(e) {...

Answer (score 1):

Your script can be slimmed down to just this, there's no need to repeat the same function to every element and slot, you can use `each()` instead. also there's no need to change id of each element you can just use the same id in css:

```
$(init);

function init() {
    $('.element').css('cursor', 'move');
    $('.element').each(function () {
        $(this).data('number', $(this).attr('id').replace('element_', '')).draggable({
            containment: '#content',
            stack: '#elements div',
            cursor: 'hand',
            revert: true
        });
    });

    // Create the element slots

    $('#slots').find('div').each(function () {
        $(this).data('number', $(this).attr('id').replace('slot_', '')).droppable({
            accept: '#elements div',
            hoverClass: 'hovered',
            drop: handleElementDrop
        });
    });
}

function handleElementDrop(event, ui) {
    var slotNumber = $(this).data('number');
    var elementNumber = ui.draggable.data('number');

    if (slotNumber == elementNumber) {
        $(this).droppable('disable');
        ui.draggable.parent().find('.info').addClass('correct');
        ui.draggable.css('cursor', 'pointer')
            .addClass('correct')
            .draggable('disable')
            .position({
            of: $(this),
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left top'
        })
            .on('click', function () {
            window.open(ui.draggable.attr('data-link'));
        });
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
    }
}
```

in `handleElementDrop` function you cad add click event handler which will fire when user put the right element on the right slot then click on it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/4JW74/)

Comment: Hey razzak, many thanks for that.  Still trying to work out how I can make just the nested element_left clickable on drop without firing off the click event on drop though...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432605/jquery-drag-and-drop-set-clickable-region-in-draggable-on-drop