# Jquery drag and drop - set clickable region in draggable on drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

This is a follow up question posted at [Jquery drag and drop - click event registers on drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432170/jquery-drag-and-drop-click-event-registers-on-drop)

I'm using jquery drag and drop.  The draggable elements contain two nested divs floated left and right.  The left div contains the text on the draggable and the right div contains a small 'info' button that toggles a tooltip.

On drop, I want the left nested div containing the text of the draggable to be clickable.  The drop is handled by the following function:

```
function handleElementDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var elementNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

  if ( slotNumber == elementNumber ) {



ui.draggable.css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
ui.draggable.parent().find('.element_left').click(function(e) {  
        window.open(ui.draggable.attr('data-link'));
    });

ui.draggable.parent().find('.info').addClass('correct');
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
  } 
}
```

Now where there is:

```
ui.draggable.parent().find('.element_left').click(function(e) {  
        window.open(ui.draggable.attr('data-link'));
    });
```

Works for the clickable left nested div OK, but the issue that I posted in my last question appears to remain.  That is, on drop, the click event is fired.  This happens very sporadically...I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/5wcaQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is not `.element_left` element it is a `info` element inside it.

Also the behaviour could be related the fact that we are registering a click event handler inside another click event handler. Try putting the event registration to a `setTimout` and see whether it is getting fixed

```
setTimeout(function(){
    ui.draggable.find('.element_left').click(function(e) { 
        window.open(ui.draggable.attr('data-link')); 
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B4ZZr/)

Comment: No...element_right div contains an anchor tag with class info.  That is the info button that is only used to show a tooltip, not to open the data-link for the element...that is done by clicking element_left.

Comment: Yep, I tried ui.draggable.find('.element_left').click(function(e) { too and still has the click event fired off sometimes.  I tried your fiddle above and did the first 3 slots and then the last slot, and the event was fired on the last slot...

Comment: The first two slots are Isolate Virus and Extract RNA.  I think I can always get it to fire by then dragging the element 'Sequence identification and phylogenetic analysis' to the last slot after the first two are done...

Comment: Great catch by Arun P Johny!  setTimeout did the trick.  Many thanks for your help.